# How to resolve graphql field parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql, arguments, apollo-server, resolve

I make resolver for this query (with parameter)

[image]

but how to update my resolver to handle the "mailtype" parameter if it moved to the email field (for example), I need to run the commented query instead of the first one
in general, I can't resolve the query field parameters (regardless of using variables)
I try to use the parent default parameter to handle them but it didn't success
here is my code (code description in image below)

```js
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql} = require('apollo-server-express');
async function startApolloServer() {
  //array of user objects
  let users =
  [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Magdalena",
      "email":"mgrewes0@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Lyndell",
      "email":"lgilbee1@yahoo.com",
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Harman",
      "email":"hgaspero2@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "id":4,
      "name":"ali",
      "email":"ali@yahoo.com",
    }
  ];
  const typeDefs = gql`
    type User {
        id: ID
        name: String
        email(mailtype: MailType): String
    }
    enum MailType{
        GMAIL
        YAHOO
    }
    type Query {
        getUserByEmailType(mailtype: MailType): [User]
    }
  `;
  const resolvers = {
    MailType: {
        GMAIL: "gmail",
        YAHOO: "yahoo"
    },
    Query: {
        getUserByEmailType: (parent, args) => users.filter(user => user.email.indexOf(args.mailtype) >= 0 ),
    },
  };
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
  await server.start();
  const app = express();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app});
  await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 7000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:7000${server.graphqlPath}`);
  return { server, app };
}
startApolloServer()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please not post a painting of your code, but a [mcve] with [text-formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Use comments to point out parts of the code, not drawn arrows.

Comment: "*how to update my resolver to handle the "mailtype" parameter if it moved to the email field*" - you don't update it at all, the `getUserByEmailType` should not handle the `mailtype` argument of the `email` field. You need to add a separate resolver for the `User.email` field which may handle that argument.

Comment: default arg value: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments ... you can 'save' parent passed arg in parent returned object

Comment: ... and/but 'moving arg' changes `return all users where emailtype=arg` into `return all users [unconditionally], return user email field where email type equal to arg` - filtering is at top querying level

Comment: @xadm but args do not contain mailType,  if the mailType passed via the email field, like the commented query

Comment: @Bergi i put the code, "You need to add a separate resolver for the User.email field which may handle that argument." could you tell me where and how to write the separated resolver for user.email.. how can i pass the user.email parameter to that resolver !!

Comment: 'main' resolver doesn't return email field (filter it out) in returned user object ... then (if requested [in query] and doesn't exist in parent=user) user.email resolver is called ... search/google for 'field resolver' ... like for fields defined in other datasource: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/#define-other-resolvers ... still **not the same logic** (all users returned) as arg in user level

Comment: thanks @xadm i solve it, here is the right code https://github.com/nsra/test-resolving-graphql-fields-arguments